# The definition of a directional derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations, derivatives

We're given that for $e \in \mathbb{R}^2$ the directional derivative of $u$ in the direction of $e$ is, 
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial e}(x,t):= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{u((x,t) + he) - u(x,t)}{h} = \frac{d}{dh}u((x,t) + he)|_{h=0}$$ and don't understand how they managed to jump from the 'middle' to the 'last' equation in this directional derivative definition. Could someone break this down for me? Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically just definition of the derivative, nothing more.

If you have
$$f(h)=u((x,t)+he)$$
then the derivative $f'(h)$ is, by definition,
$$f'(0)=\frac{\mathrm{d}f(h)}{\mathrm{d}h}|_{h=0}=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h-0}=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{u((x,t)+he)-u(x,t)}{h}$$